# Slick2D not detecting mouse movement

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

Installed Slick2D recently, however it seems that it does not detect any changes of mouse cursor position whats so ever, ie using mousePressed method always return same position. Can this be due to changes in the lwjgl natives? I feel that nobody uses Slick2D anymore...

Code:

```
package grajus;

import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class GameStart extends StateBasedGame {

public GameStart(String title) {
    super(title);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        AppGameContainer game = new AppGameContainer(new GameStart("Game"));    
        game.setDisplayMode(640, 480, false);
        game.start();
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void initStatesList(GameContainer arg0) throws SlickException {
    addState (new GameState());
}

class GameState extends BasicGameState {

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1)
            throws SlickException {}

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1,
            Graphics arg2) throws SlickException {}

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1, int arg2)
            throws SlickException {}

    @Override
    public int getID() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(int button, int x, int y) {
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);            // no matter where I press I get -161 481
    }

}

}
```

Comment: I tried running the code and it worked just fine, on which platform are you and have you tried loading in the libraries with some kind of build system like maven? And yes, java game development unfortunately slowly dies.

Comment: Have you tried checking for input in the update method with something like ``gameContainer.getInput().getMouseX()``? That would tell you if the input is working at all and might help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: @thomas88wp No it does not, still getting same -161 for some reason ..

Comment: Why not just use lwjgl's mouse adaptor?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has this problem today, I could fix it by updating to the newest lwjgl version 2.9.3

After updating lwjgl version the mouse position was detected correctly.